# How to use shell on WAMP

Tags: linux, shell, apache-http-server, wamp

Is there a way to open shell with WAMP?

I need to be able to run some UNIX commands with my local WAMP server.

Cheers

Comment: Doesn't WAMP stand for Windows Apache MySQL PHP? LAMP is Linux Apache MySQL PHP. Is the server Windows or Linux?

Comment: If it is Windows, take a look at the [GNUWin32 project](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) for Windows ports of some of the key *nix tools.

Comment: I need to be able to use shell commands to import sql files to mysql database using mysql command and do some shell scripting commands. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is for Windows with WAMP software installed

Comment: Why not just download the MySQL Workbench? You will have all of the information/functionality that you need. Your question is worded incorrectly as you do not need UNIX commands. You need to know where MySQL is installed at so that you can run MySQL commands.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned I normally run something like this mysql -u username -p DATA-BASE-NAME < data.sql and this command cannot be run on mysql console but only on linux shell.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and install MySQL with the Cygwin package.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, in WAMP, you have phpmyadmin, and inside it, you can run some SQL commands and import SQL files or dumps.

For the shell, you can consider installing [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)